# Zip a list of tuple with list of charachter

Tags: python

I've 2 list in this form:

```
name = ['John','Jack','Benny', 'Jane']

location = [(219, 459, 374, 304)]
```

When I'm doing

```
for (top, right, bottom, left), name in list(zip(location, name)):
    print(location, name)
```

I'm getting the following result:

```
[(219, 459, 374, 304)] J
```

But I want to get this result:

```
[(219, 459, 374, 304)] John
```

Also, Suppose now my list is the following:

```
name = ['John','Jack', 'Jane']

location = [(219, 459, 374, 304), (200, 459, 350, 214), (159, 349, 264, 104)]
```

How to get the result of above for loop in this form:

```
[(219, 459, 374, 304)] John
[(200, 459, 350, 214)] Jack
[(159, 349, 264, 104)] Jane
```

Comment: what is the problem `zip(name,location)`  gives me your expected output ... (to clarify `zip(['John','Jack', 'Jane'], [(219, 459, 374, 304), (200, 459, 350, 214), (159, 349, 264, 104)])` works how i think you are asking

Comment: As an aside, don't use `list` on your `zip` iterator. That is totally useless and makes your code more inefficient. It defeats the entire purpose of making `zip` a lazy iterator.

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga: In python3, if I just put zip, it does not print zip output. That's why I used list. In the final code I'm not using it. Since I took it from the code I was testing I accidentally copied put it.

Comment: One problem you have is you use `name` to refer to the elements in `name` in your `for` loop statement. If you run the loop a second time, you will get the result you are showing.

Comment: It became a habit of people to quickly down vote a question with giving any reason.. Not sure why it has been down voted.

Comment: one person voted it down ... others are giving hints and asking for clarification in the comments

Comment: I didn't downvote, but I suspect it's because your example code *is giving your desired output*.

Comment: yes..And I'm extremely grateful to them. But this one person is not very nice!

Comment: Also as an aside, note that since you use `for (top, right, bottom, left), name`, you will lose the reference to your original `name` list, and it will be garbage-collected if you don't have any other references.

Comment: No. It's not. That's why I had to ask this question.

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga: Actually this problem is from opencv. To put text we need to put 4 coordinates and a name. Those in the bracket are 4 coordinates of a rectangle and the name I want to publish in the image. Please find the example here. http://docs.opencv.org/3.1.0/dc/da5/tutorial_py_drawing_functions.html

Comment: @Beta it **is**. I and others are telling you. See my answer.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The reason you are getting

```
[(219, 459, 374, 304)] J
```

Instead of:

```
[(219, 459, 374, 304)] John
```

Is because you reused the `name` variable:

```
for (top, right, bottom, left), name in list(zip(location, name)):
    print(location, name)
```

Thus, when you run this a second time, `name` refers to the last `name` in your first attempt, presumably `'Jane'`. So the first element is `'J'` since it is iterating over the *string*.

Be careful with your variable names. And post *reproducible examples*. If you had try to do this in a fresh process as is suggested, you would have not seen this behavior.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Yes..I think you are right. Actually "name" is getting called twice, I'm getting the issue. If you run my code twice you can see only "J" is coming, not in first execution. Thanks again!

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
from itertools import izip_longest

name = ['John','Jack', 'Jane']

location = [(219, 459, 374, 304), (200, 459, 350, 214), (159, 349, 264, 104)]

new = [i for i in izip_longest(location, name) if None not in i]
```

`izip_longest` is helpful because it will allow you to filter out any occasion of two lists or tuples that do not match in length:

```
name = ['John','Jack','Benny', 'Jane']

location = [(219, 459, 374, 304)]

new = [i for i in izip_longest(location, name) if None not in i]

print new
```

Output:

```
[((219, 459, 374, 304), 'John')]
```

Comment: how does this solve the issue? (Im not sure what the issue is... but its not mismatched list sizes from what i can tell)

Comment: @JoranBeasley I see what you mean. I used `izip_longest` due to the fact that the OP's first example had the first list of length 3 and the second list of length 1, but only wanted output with the first element in the first list.

Comment: But *how would that fix anything?* Note, `new = [i for i in izip_longest(location, name) if None not in i]` is essentially eqivalent to just using `zip`!

Comment: @Ajax1234: THanks for your answer. I already tried it. But was not getting the correct answer. Also I was using python3 and in it "zip_longest" is used. But thanks again!

Answer (score 1):

I just copied and pasted your example code

```
>>> name = ['John','Jack', 'Jane']
>>> location = [(219, 459, 374, 304), (200, 459, 350, 214), (159, 349, 264, 104)]
>>> for n,loc in zip(name,location):
...    print("%s %s"%(n,loc))
...
John (219, 459, 374, 304)
Jack (200, 459, 350, 214)
Jane (159, 349, 264, 104)
```

Comment: Thanks Joran for your answer! I tried this. But was not getting the kind of result you are getting. I'll try again.